# Angular 2 http Service Error handling

Tags: angular, angular-http

I am new to angular 2 and I am working with external system for the http api calls. I want to show the api errors to the user as toster notification. But I could not use the toster server in my error handling method..

```
import { BadInput } from './../common/bad-input';
import { NotFoundError } from './../common/not-found-error';
import { AppError } from './../common/app-error';
import { Http, RequestOptions , Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

options: object;

constructor( private http: Http , private toastr: ToastrService ) { 
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token'));
  this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

}

getAll(url: string) {
  return this.http.get(environment.apiEndPoint+url,this.options)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
create(url: string,resource) {
  return this.http.post(environment.apiEndPoint+url, JSON.stringify(resource),this.options)
    .map(response => {
       this.toastr.success( 'Data Saved Successfully');
       return response.json(); 
     })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
  if (error.status === 403){
    this.toastr.error( 'User Login Failed');
    return Observable.throw(new BadInput(error.json()));
  }
  if (error.status === 500){
    this.toastr.error( 'Internal Server Error');
    return Observable.throw(new BadInput(error.json()));
  }
  if (error.status === 422){
    this.toastr.error( 'Validation Failed');
    return Observable.throw(new BadInput(error.json()));
  }

  if (error.status === 404){
    this.toastr.error( 'Not found');
    return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError(error.json()));
  }

  this.toastr.error( 'Something went wrong. Please contact Administrator!');
  return Observable.throw(new AppError(error.json()));
}
```

}

The toster is working fine with the positive response (200). If the http is throwing any error, I cound not able to handle it in the UI.

Comment: Try `.catch((err) => this.handleError(err))` instead. It's probably because the context of `this` is being lost

Comment: very nice. It is working perfectly fine. thank you @user184994 ..thank you very much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as map function, the error function expects something from server!
The map expects query result, .error() expects error object!
So you can do somethin like this:

```
getAll(url: string) {
  return this.http.get(environment.apiEndPoint+url,this.options)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

Hope it helps!!!